# How to open appstore link in UIWebView and not in app-store

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store

In my app I need to open an appStore URL inside a UIWebView. Unfortunately the behaviour seems to be to open that app in the app-store instead of in the browser.

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Usual solutions seem to be to implement the `webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool` delegate and return false if the url contains `itunes.apple.com`. However this prevents the page from opening at all, which is not what I need.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider using `SKStoreProductViewController` to present a proper native representation of the store content you want to make available.

Comment: But from my understanding that would still require the information to be shown modally, right? 

I have a scrollview with an image and a UIWebView and I need the information to show in the scroll view, not to modally segue to a new page

Comment: you should be able to add it as a child view controller

Comment: yeah, I guess this would be the way to go. I eventually figured a way around it without using itunes links in the first place, but I fiddled with your suggestion around a bit and it looked promising, even though it is impossible to disable the top bar (afaik) which didn't make much sense in a scrollview context